# Percent key ( % ) matching behavior for angle brackets ( < > )

Tags: key-bindings, search, cursor-movement

In vi it's very helpful to be able to place the cursor on a '(' or '{' or '[' character, press the '%' key, and move to the matching ')', '}', or ']'.

But this does not work for me with angle brackets ( '<' and '>' ), even though page 130 of my "Learning the vi Editor" O'Reilly book (6th edition) says it should! I am using Centos 7.2 and my 'vi' editor is actually vim 7.4.160.

Is this a version-specific thing? Or is there some switch that I can set/clear to make this work? It'd be handy for trying to make sense of HTML and Javascript.

Comment: What is `'matchpairs'` set to? You can find out by doing: `:verbose set matchpairs?`. See `:h 'matchpairs'` for more information

Comment: When I try that I see: " matchpairs=(:),{:},[:] ", which looks promising. How can I alter this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`'matchpairs'` controls what characters form pairs which `%` will work upon. You can add angle brackets by doing the following command as suggested by `:h 'matchpairs'`:

```
:set matchpairs+=<:>
```

Since `'matchpairs'` is a buffer local setting it would be best do this for the filetype you want. An example of for `cpp` filetype which can be added to your `vimrc` file:

```
augroup AngleBrackets
    autocmd!
    autocmd FileType cpp set matchpairs+=<:>;
augroup END
```

However my preferred method of setting filetype specific options is to use the `after-directory`. Add the following to `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/cpp.vim`:

```
set matchpairs+=<:>
```

Note: These examples use `cpp` as the filetype. You can use a different filetype to fit your needs.

If you truly want to make this a global change no matter the filetype add the following to your `vimrc` file:

```
setglobal matchpairs+=<:>
```

For more help see:

```
:h 'matchpairs'
:h local-options
:h 'filetype'
:h :autocmd
:h after-directory
:h setglobal
```

Comment: Thanks again. It looks like my 'vi' has a hard time displaying help text, I will see if I can improve that.