# Jumping to matching angle brackets in heavily templated C++ code

Tags: filetype-c++, delimiter-matching, jump

By heavily templated I mean it's easy to have something like this, which is a trivial example I made up:

```
#include <type_traits>
class a {};
bool operator<(a,a) { return true; };
bool b = std::is_same_v<decltype(a{} < a{}), bool>;
// poor little orphan──┘             └──married──┘
```

As you can see, provided [things are set up in such a way that <kbd>%</kbd> jumps from `<`/`>` to the (arguably) corresponding `>`/`<`](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/9729/percent-key-matching-behavior-for-angle-brackets), the <kbd>%</kbd> does jump, but <s>between the wrong pair of angle brackets</s> from the closing angle bracket to the less than operator.

Honestly I don't know if it's possible to distinguish between tempalate and "standalone" angle brackets without a "semantic-aware" parsing of the code, hence I'm asking the present question:

### Is there a plugin which allows making this semantic-aware jumps between angle brackets?

Comment: without understanding the semantics of the code, it is difficult to handle this case and match the angle bracket correctly.

Comment: You may also be interested in [vim-matchup](https://github.com/andymass/vim-matchup/issues/69).

Comment: @jdhao, interesting, and I think I'll use it, however it does not seem to provide a solution for the case I show here. [I've created an issue here](https://github.com/andymass/vim-matchup/issues/112).

Comment: Well... I wouldn't call it 100% "wrong". Even if you had an actual mismatched parenthesis (it doesn't really matter which type of bracket it is), something like `((test)`, and you press `%` while on the last parenthesis, where do you expect the cursor to go? To the first one or the second one? Both would be arguably wrong or right, depending on implementation/expectation.

Comment: @ChatterOne, the point is that your example has an _actual mismatched parenthesis_, in my example, there is no _mismatched angle brackets_; there's only _two_ angle brackets, the middle `<` being no angle bracket but just a _less than operator_. Obviously this is a consequence of looking at that line in a "semantic aware" way.

Comment: @Enrico Yes, I understand that, I'm just saying that being "semantic aware" is not as obvious as one might think. How about `a = b << 1 > 128;`? This is not templated, what do you expect to happen there? I'm just saying that these cases cannot be easily detected.

Comment: @ChatterOne, being semantic aware is not obvious (hence the present qeustion), I agree. What would I expect about `a = b << 1 > 128;`? I would expect no reasonable jump if it does not compile, but if it does compile, I would expect it to jump correctly (or not jump) depending on the semantics. For instance, if `a` and `b` are of class `A` defined as `struct A { A& operator=(int){ return *this; } };`, and you also define `int operator<<(A, int) { return 1; }`, that code compiles and runs (there's just a warning from clangd, no errors), so there should be no matching pair in that case.

Comment: @Enrico You don't need classes for that to compile, `a` and `b` can simply be `int` and `<<` is the bitwise operator to shift. But to be able to understand if those are classes, just `int`, and if there's a custom operator defined for `<<`, you need to compile the code. I don't think any plugin will ever do that.

Comment: You're right, I didn't think of that! However, there are plugins that are semantic aware, such as YouCompleteMe, which jumpts to headers/definitions/declarations/...; maybe I should ask YCM's devs if they know anything about this.